# How to combine regular expressions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be easy for those who play with regular expressions.

```
str = "Here is 'sample' test";
str = str .replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), '');
str = str .replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'), '');
```

How to combine 2nd and 3rd line, I want to combine regular expressions `new RegExp('"', 'g')` and `new RegExp("'", 'g')` into one regular expression, this will make it in one line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code to remove single and double quotes from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('["\']', 'g'), '');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
str = str.replace(/"|'/g, '')
```

Comment: The regexp literal just doesn't get enough love. Hurray for less escaping!

Answer (score 3):

```
str.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a character class for this, to match both single and double quotes you can use `['"]`.

In a full regex you would need to escape one of the quotes though.

```
var str = "here is 'sample' test";
str = str.replace(/["']/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Andrew's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077556/how-to-combine-regular-expressions-in-javascript/4077576#4077576):

```
str.replace(/"|'/, 'g')
```

And if you seeking for a good explanation then this has been discussed on a different threat where [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) explains good. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp/870506#870506).

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "Here is 'sample' test".replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), '').replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'), '');
```

An example that's basically the same as yours, except it uses method chaining.