# What is the difference between RegExp("str","i") and '/'+"str"+'/i'

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to do a case insensitive regular expression search by creating a string like so:

```
var regEx = '/'+myStr+'/i';
```

but when I use it in a search, it always returns `-1`.

If I use:

```
var regEx = RegExp(myStr,'i');
```

it works like a champ.

I'd just like to understand why?

Comment: Because the first is a String, the second is a RegExp object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213237/combining-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Comment: More so: the first is a string that results in extra garbage "/" characters in it. This will make it fail when used in a context that does normally accept strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first example will create a string, not a regular expression object.

```
var myStr = 'test';
var regEx = '/'+myStr+'/i';
console.log(typeof regEx);//string
```

Using `RegExp` will create a regular expression object.

```
var myStr = 'test';
var regEx = RegExp(myStr,'i');
console.log(typeof regEx);//object
```

Thus when you try to use the `search` method, you are searching with a string on slashes on both sides, thus getting `-1`.

```
var s = 'just a test string';
console.log(s.search('/test/'));//-1
console.log(s.search(/test/));//7
```

Of course, the string `search` method can work with a string, in which case it will search for that specific substring, which in your case does not exist, so it returns the `-1` index. In your example slashes were being added to the string, rather than producing the intended regular expression.

---

In JavaScript, there are two ways of creating a regular expression object (short of using code evaluation), a regular expression literal, and one created by the `RegExp` constructor.

A regular expression literal has to be defined at compile time, and cannot be constructed from string concatenation.

```
/test/i
```

To dynamically create a regular expression at runtime, you have to use the `RegExp` constructor.

```
RegExp('test', 'i');
```