# Combining two regex patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way of combining these two patterns? I would like to remove spaces and non-alphanumeric characters.

This does work, it just seems inefficient repeating the `replace` function.

```js
var str;
str = $('p').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');

alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>What's Happening Here!</p>
```

Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjnc8x4g/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining regular expressions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213237/combining-regular-expressions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You can combine them using the 'or' operator (`|`), like this: `/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+|\s/g`

```js
var str = $('p').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+|\s/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>What's Happening Here!</p>
```

Comment: That hat suites you :p

Answer (score 1):

You could explicity only allow numbers and letters. This will discard any white space

```
str = $('p').text().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fjnc8x4g/1/

Answer (score 0):

ypu also add `.replace` after last like

```
str = $('p').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
```

```js
var str;
str = $('p').text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p>
  What 's Happening Here!
</p>
```