# javascript regex replace all occurrences, using variables & dynamic strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all occurrences that match a certain predefined pattern.

Here's an example:

```js
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car & listens to blues!";
var replaceStr = "blue"; // dynamically fetched

var pattern = new RegExp(replaceStr, "g");
alert(str.replace(pattern, "red"));
```

This however, also replaces "blues" to "reds" which was not intended, so explored a bit on word search using \b.

This works when I define the replaceStr as /blue\b/, however how can I achieve this when replaceStr is dynamically fetched?

Comment: use `new RegExp()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Combine them like normal strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213237/combining-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Comment: var replaceStr = "blue"; replaceStr += "\\b";