# Combine two regular expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that picks up the author in the following scenarios

`Letter from author to recipient regarding topic 11-10-2018`

`Letter from author, regarding topic 10-11-2018`

I tried following the [suggestions found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213237/combining-regular-expressions-in-javascript) and this is what i have:

```
let commaRegex =  new RegExp(/(?<=from) (.+?),/, 'gi','$1');
let fromToRegex = new RegExp(/(?<=from) (.+?) (?=to)/, 'gi','$1');
let combinedRegex = new RegExp(commaRegex + '|' + fromToRegex);
let author = document.getElementById('userInput').value.match(combinedRegex);
console.log(author)
```

But the `console.log(author)` returns 'null'.

I am using this on Chrome as look behinds are not supported in all browsers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you properly read the approaches? They use `regex.source`- have you also tired using that?

Comment: Which word are you trying to get?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I am trying to get the name of the author that will always vary but will be between either the words 'from' and 'to' or between 'from' and a ','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to combine them "automatically", just use the or operator for the last part:

```
(?<=from )(.+?)(?=,| to)
```

https://regex101.com/r/xzlptd/2/

To make it work in all browsers, get rid of the look-arounds

```
from (.+?)(?:,| to)
```

and pick the first group from the match: `.match(...)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the solution provided by georg, just in case you want to combine any other two that aren't as easily substituted by one:

You have to add the sources instead of the whole object:

```js
let commaRegex =  new RegExp(/(?<=from) (.+?),/, 'gi','$1');
let fromToRegex = new RegExp(/(?<=from) (.+?) (?=to)/, 'gi','$1');
let combinedRegex = new RegExp(commaRegex.source + '|' + fromToRegex.source);

let sampleText = 'Letter from Joseph Tribbiani to recipient regarding topic 11-10-2018';

console.log(sampleText.match(combinedRegex));

sampleText = 'Letter from Joseph Tribbiani, regarding topic 11-10-2018';

console.log(sampleText.match(combinedRegex));
```