# regex exclude hit if text contains a second string match

Tags: regex, jenkins

I am trying to search thru log files to see if any warnings have appeared so that I can warn in a Jenkins pipeline using Jenkins plug in "Text Finder".

However, I have a case where I do not want hits on the string "CRIT" int he logfile if the string also contains plms.

E.g. 
I have the following text in the log file:

```
<CRIT> 23-Jun-2014::10:57:13.649 Upgrade committed
<CRIT> 23-Jun-2014::10:57:13.703 no registration found for callpoint plmsView/get_next of type=external
```

I am not interested in having a warning for the second line, so I have added the following regex to Text Finder in Jenkins:

```
WARN|ERROR|<ERR>|/^(?=<CRIT>)(?=^(?:(?!plms).)*$).*$/
```

This should get a hit on CRIT only if the string does not also contain plms, i.e the first line, but I do not get a hit on either line.

I got the code from here: [Combine Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp)

Could someone please help me correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
WARN|ERROR|<ERR>|<CRIT>(?!.*?no registration found)
```

Change the `no registration found` part to match the `<CRIT>` message you want to exclude.

This expression matches also for the line:

```
<INFO> User WARNER registered
```

so you should consider using something like:

```
^(WARN|ERROR|<ERR>|<CRIT>(?!.*?no registration found))
```

that matches only if the tokens are at the beginning of the line (change the tokens accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
^<CRIT>(.(?!plms))*$
```

[**Demo and explanation**](http://regex101.com/r/nH4kM8)