# How to combine multiple .net regex into one?

Tags: c#, regex

```
var keyList = new[] { "AccountKey", "PrivateKey", "APIKey", "DefectiveKeyGracefulExpiration" };
var multiplePatternMatching = string.Format("({0})", string.Join("|", keyList));
var keyRegex = string.Format(@"(?s)<([\s<]?{0}[\s<]*)>.*?</\1>", multiplePatternMatching);
```

And I have another regex:

```
var passwordRegex = @"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>.*?</\1>";
```

How to combine `keyRegex` and `passwordRegex` into one regex? I known that I need to use `|` but I don't know how.

I'm trying to use `|` like this:

`var keyOrPasswordRegex = string.Format( @"(?s)<([\s<]?{0}[\s<]*)>.*?</\1>|(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>.*?</\2>", multiplePatternMatching);`

but it's doesnt work

Input:

```
<job xmlns:i="..." xmlns="...">
<password>asdfasdf</password>
<adminPassword>asd</adminPassword>
<AccountKey>asd</AccountKey>
<AccountKeyZ>asd</AccountKeyZ>
...</job>
```

Actual result:

```
<job xmlns:i="..." xmlns="...">
 <></>
 ​<></>
​<AccountKey></AccountKey>
​<AccountKeyZ>asd</AccountKeyZ>
​...</job>
```

Expected result:

```
<job xmlns:i="..." xmlns="...">
<password></password>
<adminPassword></adminPassword>
<AccountKey></AccountKey>
<AccountKeyZ>asd</AccountKeyZ>
...</job>
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp

Comment: I think you have a problem with a backreference here, you need to be careful not to break the order of capturing groups. Use `var multiplePatternMatching = string.Format("(?:{0})", string.Join("|", keyList)); var keyRegex = string.Format(@"(?s)<([^\s<]*{0}[^\s<]*)>.*?</\1>", multiplePatternMatching);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, and how to combine `keyRegex` with `passwordRegex` ?

Comment: I think by adding "password" to the `keyList`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, because `password` it's completely different regex

Comment: Without examples, it is not possible to help you more. `<([\s<]?{0}[\s<]*)>.*?</\1>` makes no sense.

Comment: I am putting my children to bed, I will have a look in half an hour.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that my `passwordRegex` is with `i` and `^`, `keyRegex` without. And `passwordRegex` have `*password` and `keyRegex` have `?{0}`

Comment: Ok, I see that key regex means a regex for tags that include `key` word and their content must be reset. Try `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*|(?:AccountKey|PrivateKey|APIKey|DefectiveKeyGracefulExpiration))>.*?</\1>", "<$1></$1>")`. **See [this demo](http://ideone.com/ks55aM).**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much! You save my live! It works! Set your answer not in the comment if you want

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an alternation like this:

```
var keyList = new[] { "AccountKey", "PrivateKey", "APIKey", "DefectiveKeyGracefulExpiration" };
var multiplePatternMatching = string.Format("({0})", string.Join("|", keyList));
var rx = string.Format(@"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*|{0})>.*?</\1>", multiplePatternMatching);
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, rx, "<$1></$1>"));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ks55aM) and a  [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fsi)%3C(%5B%5E%5Cs%3C%5D*password%5B%5E%5Cs%3C%5D*%7C(%3F%3AAccountKey%7CPrivateKey%7CAPIKey%7CDefectiveKeyGracefulExpiration))%3E.*%3F%3C%2F%5C1%3E&i=%3Cjob%20xmlns%3Ai%3D%22...%22%20xmlns%3D%22...%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cpassword%3Easdfasdf%3C%2Fpassword%3E%0D%0A%3CadminPassword%3Easd%3C%2FadminPassword%3E%0D%0A%3CAccountKey%3Easd%3C%2FAccountKey%3E%0D%0A%3CAccountKeyZ%3Easd%3C%2FAccountKeyZ%3E%0D%0A...%3C%2Fjob%3E&r=%3C%241%3E%3C%2F%241%3E). Explanation:

- `<` - a literal `<`
- `([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*|{0})` - (*Group 1*) 0+ characters other than whitespace and `<` followed with a word `password` and followed with 0+ characters other than whitespace and `<`  or an alternation group of `AccountKey`, `PrivateKey`, `APIKey` or `DefectiveKeyGracefulExpiration` (those listed in the `multiplePatternMatching` variable)
- `>` - a literal `>`
- `.*?</\1>` - any 0+ symbols, as few as possible, up to the first `</` followed with the contents of the first capture group and `>`.