# Validating a numeric, 12-digit String containing a dash using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate that a given String contains up to 12 digits and exactly one dash.

**Initial RegEx:** `^[0-9]*-?[0-9]*$`

**Modified RegEx:** `^([0-9]*-?[0-9]*){1,12}$`

Example (should be valid): `12356978-9`

The problem is that the first RegEx doesn't validate the length, and the second one doesn't work.

**Note: Everything must be done in regex, not checking length using string.length()**

Comment: It would be good if you give some example strings you want to compare with.

Comment: Will be there be only one digit after a dash?

Comment: 123465789-10 is valid, 123456789-1011 is invalid because of lenght,123465789 is invalid because of no dash in it

Comment: Something along `String s = ... ; return s.length()<=13 && s.matches("^\\d+-\\d+$");`?

Comment: @Seth You changed the question. Nowhere it was said that no dashes was an acceptable solution!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Noted. The "up to" part confused me, I thought it was meant as "up to 12 digits as well as up to one dash". Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ugly way:

```
^([0-9]-[0-9]{1,11}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,10}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{1,9}| ...)$
```

Using lookahead, combining two conditions:

```
^(?=\\d*-\\d*$)(?=.{1,13}$).*$
```

(Inspired by [this Alan Moore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870506/5375403))

Comment: The second one should be the accepted answer. I'd +1 again if I could, but I already did :(

Answer (score 2):

If you can use extra conditions outside of the regex:

```
String s = ... ;
return s.length()<=13 && s.matches("^\\d+-\\d+$");
```

If a dash can start or end the string, you can use the following:

```
String s = ... ;
return s.length()<=13 && s.matches("^\\d*-\\d*$");
```

Comment: Any idea on how to implement in pure regex?

Comment: Yes, you can then implement @JiriTousek 's solution. Not very readable, but will do the job. This doesn't mean that there is no solution, just that if there is, other than Jiri Tousek, I don't know it.