# Remove vowels,white spaces and duplicate characters

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to trim a string and remove any vowel and white space and duplicate characters.

Here's the code I'm using

```
Function TrimString(strString As String) As String
   Dim objRegex As Object

   Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

   With objRegex
       .Global = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "[aeiou\s]"
       TrimString = .Replace(strString, vbNullString)
       .Pattern = "(.)\1+"
       TrimString = .Replace(TrimString, "$1")
   End With
End Function
```

Is there a way to combine both patterns instead of doing this in 2 steps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp

Comment: It is tricky. Please provide some sample strings with expected output. Try `.pattern = "[aeiou\s]+|([^aeiou\s])(?:[aeiou\s]*\1)+"` and `TrimString = .Replace(strString, "$1")`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RI8lTq/1).

Comment: Any feedback???

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = ".*?([^aeiou\s]).*?"
    TrimString = .Replace(TrimString, "$1$1")
End With
```

I'm not familiar with VBA but if there is a way to just return matches instead of replacing them in the original string then you could use the following pattern

```
[^aeiou\s]
```

And return this:

```
$&$&
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two replacements:

1. Removing `[aeiou\s]` matches, e.g. `niarararrrrreghtatt` turns into `nrrrrrrrghttt`
2. Replacing each chunk of identical chars with the first occurrence turns `nrrrrrrrghttt` into `nrght`.

That means, you need to match the first pattern both as a separate alternative and as a "filler" between the identical chars.

The pattern you may use is

```
.pattern = "[aeiou\s]+|([^aeiou\s])(?:[aeiou\s]*\1)+"
TrimString = .Replace(strString, "$1")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RI8lTq/1).

**Details**

- `[aeiou\s]+` - 1+ vowels or whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `([^aeiou\s])` - Capturing group 1: any char other than a vowel or a whitespace char
- `(?:[aeiou\s]*\1)+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `[aeiou\s]*` - 0+ vowel or whitespace chars
  - `\1` - backreference to Group 1, its value

Note that `.` is changed into `[^aeiou\s]` since the opposite has already been handled with the first alternation branch.