# Combine 2 or more regex in 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I've 2 regular expression:

1. `string regex1 = "(?i)(^(?!^.*?admin)(?!^.*?admin[admin\d]).*$)";`  this will check for 'admin' substring in the given string and case is insensitive.
2. `string regex2 = "^[^<>?]{5,100}$";` this will check for special char(^<>?) and length between 5 to 100 only.

I want a regular expression where both the regex can be validated at once with the use of only single regex.

Ex-

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="Validation Failed!"
    ValidationExpression="(?i)(^(?!^.*?admin)(?!^.*?admin[admin\d]).*$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="Length Validation Failed!"
    ValidationExpression="^[^<>?]{5,100}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Q. Can we have a single "RegularExpressionValidator" that serves both the above functionality?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp

Comment: Thanks ycansener, even your mention link is learning for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?i)(^(?!^.*?admin)(?!^.*?admin[admin\d]).*$)` regex is too redundant, it is equal to `(?i)^(?!^.*?admin).*$`. It basically matches any string that contains no `admin` substring.

The `^[^<>?]{5,100}$` regex disallows `<`, `>` and `?` in the string and sets string length limit.

Combining the two is done by replacing the `.*` in the first pattern with the consuming part of the second regex (`[^<>?]{5,100}`):

```
(?i)^(?!^.*?admin)[^<>?]{5,100}$
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!^.*?admin)` -  no `admin` substring allowed anywhere after 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[^<>?]{5,100}` - five to a hundred chars other than `<`, `>` and `?`
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor Stribiżew, I simply copied your answer and it's working as expected :)

Comment: @Bit2Dev Also, see [the regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/mvGkc2/1).

Comment: Hey @Wiktor Stribiżew, I found 1 issue, the above mentioned regex (?i)^(?!^.*?admin)[^<>?]{5,100}$ is working fine in my POC but if put in the required project, its throws error in WebResource.axd file.

Comment: @Bit2Dev The pattern in the answer will work on the server side, it won't work on the client side as JS RegExp does not support inline modifiers. You must remove `(?i)` and use `^(?!^.*?[Aa][Dd][Mm][Ii][Nn])[^<>?]{5,100}$`