# Combining Regex 'in between' AND 'do not contain'

Tags: regex

I've tried to combine two Regex with `AND` but failed at the attempt.

1. Pick up anything between '[[' and (']]' or '|') in direct succession :

```
(?<=(\[\[))(.*?)(?=(\||(\]\])))
```

2. Doesn't contain 'http' :

```
^(?:(?!http).)*$
```

My best try was

```
(?=(?<=(\[\[))(.*?)(?=(\||(\]\]))))(?=^(?:(?!http).)*$).*$
```

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/870506 but it is not working.

My goal is to get all the intenal links in a dokuwiki page typically : 'my_page', 'my_other_page', but not 'http://your_page' in :

```
[[my_page]]

[[my_other_page|this is my other page]]

[[http://your_page|this is your page]]
```

Comment: Try `\[\[(?!https?:\/\/)[^][|]*(?:\|[^][]*)?]]`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uEyJAP/1).

Comment: Can you just apply one regex after the next in your code? Sometimes that's easier than coming up with a Super RegEx...

Comment: Thanks but I need to get rid of the brackets as well I want to match 'my_page' and 'my_other_page' only.

Comment: Yes I thought about that : applying another regex afterward. but the first result would be store in an array and so I would have to do loop to all the results and check them, a bit more ugly, but I can do that.

Comment: Is it OK for http to exist outside the delimiters? eg `[[my_other_page|foo http bar]]` should match `my_other_page`? Does matching input always start/end with delimiters?

Comment: To @Bohemian, yes it is ok. In dokuwiki all external link start by http in between '[[' and (']]' or '|') . If there is no http it means it is an internal link. So [[my_other_page|foo http bar]] should match my_other_page.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could make use of a [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach:

```
\[\[https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[\[\K[^][|]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[\[https?:\/\/` Match `[[https://` with optional `s`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Consument the characters that you want to avoid
- `|` Or
- `\[\[\K` Match `[[` and forget what is matched so far
- `[^][|]+` Match 1+ times any char except `]` `[` or `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Be4d65/1)

```
$strings = [
    "[[my_page]]",
    "[[my_other_page|this is my other page]]",
    "[[http://your_page|this is your page]]",
];

$re = '/\[\[https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[\[\K[^][|]+/';

foreach ($strings as $s){
    if (preg_match($re, $s, $matches)) {
        var_dump($matches[0]);
    }    
}
```

Output

```
string(7) "my_page"
string(13) "my_other_page"
```

To verify the optional part with `|` and the closing `]]` you can use a negative lookahead

```
\[\[https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[\[\K[^][|]+(?=(?:\|[^][]*)?]])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GXONBB/1)

Or if the last part can also contain `]` or `[`

```
\[\[https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[\[\K[^][|]+(?=(?:\|.*?)?]])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8yRdp/1)

Answer (score 1):

Then use

```
(?<=\[\[)(?!https?:\/\/)[^][|]+
(?<=\[\[)(?!https?:\/\/)[^][|]+(?=(?:\|[^][]*)?]])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxOyH7/2)

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[\[)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `[[`
- `(?!https?:\/\/)` - a negative lookahead that cancels the match if there is `http://` or `https://` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^][|]+` - one or more chars other than `]`, `[` and `|`
- `(?=(?:\|[^][]*)?]])` - a positve lookahead that requires the following sequence of patterns immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `(?:\|[^][]*)?` - an optional occrurrence of a `|` and then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]]` - a `]]` string.

**NOTE**: Depending on the regex flavor, you may need to escape `]` or/and `[` chars in the character class, i.e. `[^][]` => `[^\][]` (JavaScript `RegExp`) or `[^\]\[]` (Java, Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Regex Pattern with some adjustments to Wiktor Stribiżew's answer in the comment section. By using lookahead and lookbehind, you can deselect the brackets.

```
(?<=\[\[)(?!https?:\/\/)[^][|]*(?:\|[^][]*)?(?=]])
```

Comment: Almost perfect thank you very much. It just grabs '| this is my other page' and I would like to not have it. The goal is to have only the first part of what follows '[[' and not what is after '|' if there is one.

I have to admit that I don't understand much about all of this regex, but thank you so much