# Is there a way to combine two different Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two different Regex formuals, one for replacing spaces, commas, and periods with an underscore: `/[ ,.]/g,"_"` and another one removing symbols `/[!@#$%^&*]/g,""`.
Is there a way to combined these two together into one expression?

Comment: Yes, string.replace can take in a handler function that you can use to differentiatee the 2 cases. But it'd be cleaner to just invoke.replace twice.

Comment: Thank you, I have .replace twice and its working great. Is that the cleanest way to use 2 different cases?

Comment: Yes, when the replace-with string is different (i.e. '_' v ''), 2 replaces is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both Regex formulas using logic operators inside (OR and AND). [This answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp).

Comment: not really, because you can't give 2 different results (to what to change it)