# Regex to get string until "-" (if exists) and then remove 2 last characters

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to use in python that captures one group containing the whole string minus the last 2 characters, but if the string have a "-" , then ignore it and all after it.

Ex:

abcde  = `abc`

jklmno-pqrs  = `jklm`

I think it would be a mix between  `(.*)..$`  and  `^([^-]*)` , but I dont know how to combine them.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp

Comment: Why don't you just use a regex to extract the string until `-` and then use `[:-2]` to remove the last 2 characters?

Comment: If you write this as a running program that demonstrates the problem, including a print of what you get from your regex, then we have the basis for tested solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a capture group matching any char except `-` followed by matching 2 chars other than `-`

```
^([^-\n]+)[^-\n]{2}(?:-.*)?$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^-\n]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more chars other than `-` (add `\n` to not match a newline)
- `[^-\n]{2}` Match 2 chars other than `-`
- `(?:-.*)?` Optionally match `-` followed by 0+ times any char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wLx11n/1)

For example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^([^-\n]+)[^-\n]{2}(?:-.*)?$"
s = ("abcde\n""jklmno-pqrs")
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['abc', 'jklm']
```

Comment: @JefersonCorrea You are welcome. If you don't need the whole match, you might also shorten the pattern to `^([^-\n]+)[^-\n]{2}` See https://regex101.com/r/tqlrGn/1

Answer (score -1):

You can combine two regex using pipe delimiter like this

```
re.findall('(.*)..$|^([^-]*)', string)
```

for reference '|' pipe delimiter is used for grouping multiple regular expressions

Comment: This matches `jklmno-pqrs` as `jklmno-pq`.

Comment: The expressions are valid, but when you combine them, it first matches the [:-2] sequence.