# Regex validation for a specific value with React Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik, yup

First is, I want to validate the field that if the user type a character that is not existing in this (e.g.): `/[ùûüÿ€’“”«»–àâæçéèêëïîôœ]/` the error message will be triggered from Yup.

Second is, I want to concatenate the 3 variables with Regex validation.

Here's the code:

```
const validChars1 = /[A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+={};:’”,./<>?| \\\\\ [\]]*$/;
const validChars2 = /[ùûüÿ€’“”«»–àâæçéèêëïîôœ]/;
const validChars3 = /[áéíóúüñ¿]/;
const mainValidator = validChars1 + validChars2 + validChars3;
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    primaryInformation: yup.object({
      externalEmployeeId: yup
        .string()
        .matches(mainValidator, "Please enter valid name")
        .required(intl.get("userManagement.editor.requiredFieldError"))

//Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'RegExp' and 'RegExp'
```

Please help me out of this problem, thank you!

Comment: Have you considered that it is not allowed to use + with regexp as the message says?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine Regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp)

Answer (score 0):

While you can't compose RegExps like this with plain JavaScript, you can do

```
const validChars1 = /[A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+={};:’”,./<>?| \\\\\ [\]]*$/;
const validChars2 = /[ùûüÿ€’“”«»–àâæçéèêëïîôœ]/;
const validChars3 = /[áéíóúüñ¿]/;
const mainValidator = new RegExp(
  validChars1.source 
  + validChars2.source 
  + validChars3.source
);
// etc...
```

There is another problem with your RegExps though: the first one ends with the `$` assertions that matches the end of the input. A RegExp of the form `/a$b/` will never succeed because `$b` is contradictory. neither `"a"` nor `"ab"` can satisfy it. for `"a"`, the `$` will succeed, but the `b` will fail, and conversely for `"ab"`.

If you want to compose RegExps without resorting to source string manipulation, you can have a look at [compose-regexp](https://github.com/pygy/compose-regexp.js) which would let you write code like this:

```
import {sequence} from 'compose-regexp'

const validChars1 = /[A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()+={};:’”,./<>?| \\\\\ [\]]*/;
const validChars2 = /[ùûüÿ€’“”«»–àâæçéèêëïîôœ]/;
const validChars3 = /[áéíóúüñ¿]/;
const mainValidator = sequence(validChars1, validChars2, validChars3);
```